Regex for checking max allowed character length and for having specific max number of lines
im trying to create a regex pattern check where the input line contains specific max characters (5) in length and there are max allowed number of lines is 10.
Each of these 10 lines needs to follow this max characters check of 5.
Input to match (Valid):
123A
123
12345
123
123
123
123
12345
12345
Test


input to match (inValid):
    12345
    123
    12345
    123
    123
    123
    123
    12345
    12345
   Test123123
    pat

Regex :
 @Pattern(regexp = "^([a-zA-Z0-9 \n]{1,10}+$)"

The above pattern is not achieving my expected
Please help in this regex suggestion im not getting the correct output for pattern matching

Read the tag information of [[tag:pattern-matching]]

You don't have to use regex for everything. That's simply not a very good fit

@g00se ur saying it is not possible ?

@user24714692 i will need limit on the max number of lines of 10 lines also

boolean valid = input.lines().count() <= 10 && input.lines().allMatch(s ->s.length() <= 5); is a better fit. And is much more readable and maintainable

input line contains specific max characters: What characters do you want to allow in each line? Only letters and digits or something more?

alphanumeric characters

The pattern that you tried has a character class [a-zA-Z0-9 \n] that matches a single character and the quantifier after it {1,10}+ repeats that 1-10 times (where the + after the quantifier makes it a possessive quantifier which you also can omit)
So you are not repeatedly matching 1-10 lines but 1-10 characters.
You might use:
(?im)^[a-z0-9]{1,5}(?:\R[a-z0-9]{1,5}){0,9}$

The pattern matches:

(?im) Inline modifier for case insensitive and multiline
^ Start of string
[a-z0-9]{1,5} Match 1-5 times a character a-z or a digit 0-9
(?: Non capture group

\R Match any Unicode newlines
[a-z0-9]{1,5} Match the allowed characters again 1-5 times


){0,9} Close the non capture group and repeat it 0-9 times
$ End of string

See a regex demo.
In Java
String regex = "^[a-z0-9]{1,5}(?:\\R[a-z0-9]{1,5}){0,9}$";


This should be the marked answer

@anubhava if i input "test \n test123 \n 123" until 9 lines have been exceeded it doesnt detect the length exceeded check.
new line for me is by \n how will this be incorporated in the above regex ?

@brazil: Please edit your question and show this non-working input in question so that it can be properly answered.

@brazil Using \R will also match \n Note that test123 is longer than 5 characters. Also there are spaces in here "test \n test123 \n 123"

@Thefourthbird not matching with the above provided regex when we put "hello\nworksl\ntest123" --upto 5 lines then it should throw error, im more concerned about the line count not working with \n provided in java code input

@brazil So you want to match 5-10 lines instead of 1-10 lines? Can you create a regex101 link with what you want and do not want to match and share it here?

@Thefourthbird this is my input string = erwersn\nerwersn\nerwersn\nwersn\nerwersn\nwersn\nerwersn\nwersn\ndddd\ndfdfd
this contains 10 lines so if i add another \ntest it should exceed the 10 max line allowed count check

@brazil See https://regex101.com/r/mUUPzY/1 Your example contains strings which exceed the 5 character limit. If you want to throw an exception you would have to do that yourself, a regex matches or it does not match.

@Thefourthbird the issue is when we use this regex in testing with JAva it is not working as expected, although it can been in the link correctly the max line characters is still required to be 10, with max number of line is 5

@brazil Can you share the javacode here https://www.ideone.com/ and paste the link back in the comments so I can try to help you out

The string satisfies the stated requirements if and only if it matches the following regular expression:
(?ix)            # invoke general, case independent and free-spacing modes
^                # match beginning of the string
(?!              # begin a negative lookahead
  (?:.*\R){10}   # match 10 lines
  .              # match a character
)                # end negative lookahead
(?:              # begin non-capture class
  [a-z0-9]{0,5}  # match up to 5 chars in char class
  \R             # match line terminator
)*               # end non-capture class and execute zero or more times
[a-z0-9]{0,5}?   # optionally match up to 5 chars in char class
$                # match end of string

Valid string demo
Too many lines demo
Line too long demo
Invalid character present demo

You'd probably want to use a pattern, similar to: (?m)(?:^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$[\s\r\n]*){1,10}, which can be simplified to (?im)(?:^[A-Z0-9]+$[\s\r\n]*){1,10}.
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(?m)(?:^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$[\\s\\r\\n]*){1,10}";
        final String string = "Input to match (Valid):\n"
                + "123A\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "Test\n\n\n\n"
                + "123A\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "Test\n\n\n"
                + "input to match (inValid):\n"
                + "    12345\n"
                + "    123\n"
                + "    12345\n"
                + "    123\n"
                + "    123\n"
                + "    123\n"
                + "    123\n"
                + "    12345\n"
                + "    12345\n"
                + "   Test123123\n"
                + "    pat";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}

Prints
Full match: 123A
123
12345
123
123
123
123
12345
12345
Test




Full match: 123A
123
12345
123
123
123
123
12345
12345
Test





Note:

You can also limit the number of chars in each line, if you want, using similar patterns, such as (?m)(?:^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}$[\s\r\n]*){1,10}.

(?m): means a multiline flag.

(?i): means an insensitive flag (e.g., Alice, ALICE, and BOB and bob are all allowed and case sensitivity does not matter).

(?:): is a non-capture group, as oppose to () which automatically captures and records a specific part of a pattern in the memory.

^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}$ means that each line consists of 1 to 6 non-space chars, including only these chars: [a-zA-Z0-9].

[\s\r\n]*: paves the way for taking the next line.

{1,10}: means one to 10 lines.



Comment:
@user85421: BTW I suspect that [\s\r\n]* allows empty or blank lines (not counting to the limit of 10 lines) and BTW2 \s already includes \r and \n.

Just in case, based on the above comment, if we only need exactly upto 10 lines including empty lines, we would use:
(?im)(?:^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$[\\s\\r\\n]){1,10}


Code

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(?im)(?:^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$[\\s\\r\\n]){1,10}";
        final String string = "Input to match (Valid):\n"
                + "123A\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "12345\n\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n\n\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123A\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "12345\n\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n\n\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "Test\n\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "12345\n"
                + "Test\n\n"
                + "123A\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "12345\n\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n"
                + "123\n\n\n"
                + "12345";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}


Prints
Full match: 123A
123
12345

123
123
123


123

Full match: 123A
123
12345

123
123
123
123



Full match: 12345
12345
Test

12345
12345
Test

123A
123

Full match: 12345

123
123
123
123


how will {1,6} restrict number of lines to 10 ?

"each line must start with" : better "each line consists of" -- "non-space char" :  missing some international chars :-/

@user24714692 what does (?:) mean ?

@brazil check the documentation: "a non-capturing group"

BTW I suspect that [\s\r\n]* allows empty or blank lines (not counting to the limit of 10 lines) and BTW2 \s already includes \r and \n

but does that include empty/blank lines? The question does not mention "at least one char", neither if empty/blank lines are allowed or also counting to the limit

to solve that + can be added instead of *

I disagree - I cannot see, from given question, that empty/blank lines are to be ignored, actually, based on posted examples, we could even assume that at least 3 chars are needed per line

for empty/blank lines what changes would be needed @user24714692

@brazil at first you must clearly describe - in the question. not as comment - what is to happen with empty lines (just a newline/carriage return)  and blank lines (line with white space). Should these be accepted? Do these lines add to the line count (up to 10 lines)?
